# New Zealand Covid Test on Arrival: Is it still required?

Tags: covid-19, new-zealand

We are planning to go to New Zealand next month. I'm trying to find the Covid entry requirements but it's been very confusing and contradictory

The embassy's website states (https://nz.usembassy.gov/covid-19-information/)

> **Is a negative COVID-19 test (PCR and/or serology) required for entry?** You do not need a pre-departure test to enter New Zealand. Most travelers need to be vaccinated and take 2 rapid antigen tests (RATs) after arriving in New Zealand.

However the NZ government website says (https://covid19.govt.nz/international-travel/)

> If you have COVID-19 symptoms when you arrive in New Zealand by air, we encourage you to take a rapid antigen test (RAT). You can get free RATs at the airport, please take some.

That sounds like testing is optional and only based on symptoms.

So did they remove the requirements of testing twice on arrival? What would be the most accurate and up-to-date source for this type of information ?

**EDIT**

I found another source that claims the testing on arrival as been discontinued and that proof of vaccination is also not needed anymore. Hopefully someone can confirm from recent travel.
https://www.travellerdeclaration.govt.nz/

Comment: It’s funny that they’re still holding on the logic of travelers being any more dangerous than locals :-)

Comment: The problem here is that I can't tell what exactly they are holding on to :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [IATA's COVID map](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm):

> New Zealand
>
> Published 21.12.2022
>
> COVID-19 entry regulations lifted.

So as of December 21st 2022, New Zealand no longer has any regulations whatsoever in regards to COVID and travel. The US Embassy page you've linked to hasn't been updated since August 2022 and is thus out of date.